# How to concatenate arrays in Java Card

Tags: javacard

Java has lot of ways concatenate arrays but it seems Java Card has none of it. Is there a way?

---

For example i want to concatenate those two array

```
byte[] a= {(byte) 'P', (byte) 'K'};
byte[] b= {(byte) 'T', (byte) 'G'};
```

What i want:

```
byte[] C= {(byte) 'P', (byte) 'K', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'G'};
```

is there any way?

Comment: You can have array longer enough to store concatenated value ,say C.Then use Util.arraycopy() method to copy array A and B into C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java Card resources are scarce, so arrays will never be concatenated. Array concatenation would create a new object, which means additional memory will have to be claimed.

Best practices are to only create objects with the `new` operator (for persistent arrays in EEPROM/flash or `JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray` and friends for transient memory (RAM) during installation / personalization and not during normal operation in the field.

In order to concatenate arrays you can use `Util.arrayCopy()` with offset and length to copy data between already existing arrays including the APDU buffer.

Similarly almost all library calls working with buffers will always require an offset and length as well so pre-existing array (buffers) can be used - at the cost of boundary checking, which you will have to do yourself.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no API available for this.

Comment: Although this is correct I think it is a bit short for an answer. It's not that hard to show an alternate solution or to explain why it is missing.

Comment: perhaps I believe the user already know the alternative solution ? How hard it is to concatenate two arrays when the user is already working on java card.